# How to retain values of a column for rows which are getting deleted

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlite3 with sqlalchemy as ORM layer. I have a table STOPS with columns id, name, feature, added_date. I need to delete many rows from it for that I used

```
session.query(Stop).filter(Stop.id.in_ (stop_id_list)).delete(synchronize_session='fetch')
```

But I need to keep the values of the added_date column. 
Can it be done without hitting the db twice? Does these stop object remains accessible once deleted?

Comment: Really, simply query them and then delete the rows. Sending two queries to the database is really not a big deal, especially if it's as simple as selecting data filtered by what appears to be the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted objects are deleted.

You need a separate query to get the `added_date` values, but after the first statement, all the data will be in the cache, so you will not actually hit the disk twice.

For correctness, ensure that both SQL statements are executed in the same [transaction](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/session_transaction.html).

Comment: So, if I do again
`session.query(Stop).filter(Stop.id.in_ (stop_id_list)).all()` then I should get the data right? But it is returning an empty list.

Comment: Read the first sentence of my answer again. The must read the data before deleting it.